Motivation for fixing $\lambda$ in ridge regression
In ridge regression, you want to optimize say:
$$
f(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_n)=\sum_n(y_n-\beta_0+\beta_1x^1_n,+\beta_2x^2_n)^2
$$
where
$x^i=(x_1^i,x_2^i,...,x_N^i)$
subject to
$||(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2)||_2\leq c$.
We can define $\mathcal{L}(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2,\lambda)=f(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2)-\lambda(c-||(\beta_0,\beta_1\beta_2)||_2)$. Henceforth, we can look for critical points of $\mathcal{L}$.
However, from what I understand, instead of optimizing over $\lambda$ and then optimize over just $(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2)$, and this gives the form for ridge regression. My question is, why do we fix $\lambda$, instead of trying to find $(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2,\lambda)$ that such that $\mathcal{L}$ is zero, and hence, $f$ is optimal for those $\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2$?

Last paragraph is unclear. What do you mean by 'and this gives the form of ridge regression'?

If you hold $\lambda$ constant, the function you are minimizing is the one given in ridge regression.

I am not sure I understand your question, but the "minimum" cost is when lambda is zero. so optimising lambda as well as coefficients on training set is misguided. rather what we are trying to ask is what is the minimum error achievable with any specific cost of coefficients.

and that cost (=lambda) is determined from an independent data set. ( or from a bayesian viewpoint, the expected range of your coefficients etc)

One reason is computational.  There is an efficient closed form solution for optimising the regression coefficients for a fixed $\lambda$, whereas there probably isn't going to be a similarly efficient algorithm for jointly optimising $\beta$ and $\lambda$ together.  This is especially true if the "normal equations" for ridge regression are solved in canonical form, in which case $\lambda$ can then be optimised at an essentially negligible additional cost.

That makes sense. From the closest form solution for ridge regression, as $\lambda$ increases, the solution is more likely to underfit the data. Would there perhaps be a problem overfitting the data if you tried to optimize treating $\lambda$ as a variable?

@user124910 yes, absolutely it could, in practice I think integrating $\lambda$ out would be better than optimising it (optimisation is the root of all evil in statistics - well a lot of it anyway ;o).  I have used an L1 regularisation term with regression where $\lambda$ was integrated out analytically and it worked quite well for a lot of problems.

This is because $\lambda$ is a hyper-parameter, unlike $\beta$ which is a parameter. You could do what you are suggesting to do as well, but you will end up with a different model then, i.e., the MLE estimator would be different since the mean and the variance, i.e., $\mathbb{E[f(\beta)]}$ and $\mathbb{V[f(\beta)]}$ would now include the $\lambda$ term. As Dikran mentions, this might not have a closed form solution.
You would then have to do a bunch of additional stuff for these estimators (now, $\beta$ and $\lambda$). Unlike the normal equation, whereby we know a lot about their asymptotic behavior and distributional properties, you won't know a lot about this new estimators, and you would most likely have to bootstrap and find out yourself.
You can think of $\lambda$ as model selection in the same way we think of features selection. Assume we have a feature $x^{i}$ and we choose to scale it with some constant $z$. How do we choose $z$? Well, you could include it in the optimization or you could fix it outside of it. Most times we choose to fix it outside because otherwise you would need to implement a custom solution. It's the same with $\lambda$. You could specify the model with it, but then the optimization would need to be custom-implemented.

The distinction between parameters and hyperparameters is often computational rather than statistical.  In this paper I treat some of the traditional hyperparameters of a kernel model as parameters, and it works very well https://doi.org/10.1016/j.neunet.2014.01.011 .  In this case $\lambda$ can also be viewed as structural risk minimisation as it allows you to create nested hypothesis/model classes of increasing complexity as you make $\lambda$ smaller.

I would also argue that the mean and variance for conventional ridge regression not including the variance due to estimation of $\lambda$ is not necessarily a good thing.  It is possible to get overfitting in the selection of $\lambda$, so there may be benefits in joint estimation.

Including or not including the variance? Тhe usual way of preventing overfitting is some-sort of a out-sample testing when grid-searching $\lambda$, e.g., cross-validation. However, indeed, if you jointly estimate, you most likely won't have to do that.

ot of sample testing doesn't prevent overfitting in selecting $\lambda$, the best it can do is detect it.  It isn't that difficult to overfit cross-validation when optimising hyperparameters https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf  For small datasets, it may be better to take a fully Bayesian approach and integrate over $\lambda$ (and any other hyperparameters) rather than optimising (which could be viewed as fitting them jointly, I suppose?),


My question is, why do we fix $\lambda$, instead of trying to find $(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2,\lambda)$ that such that $\mathcal{L}$ is zero

You don't want to optimize $\mathcal{L}$ directly. That would lead to overfitting.
The point of introducing the penalty with $\lambda \neq 0$ is in reducing overfitting and improving the general application of a fit.
The optimal value of $\lambda$ is found by a loss function on another data set. That is the loss that you want to minimize.
The parameter $\lambda$ is not entirely fixed here. It is varied in order to find an optimum in that second loss function.

The image below illustrates this. It is an example with the 'polynomial order' instead of the parameter '$\lambda$', but the idea is the same.

As function of increasing the 'polynomial order' parameter the model becomes better in fitting the original data (the training error redices), this is the blue line dropping while we increase the polynomial order.

However the red line increases at some point. This red line explains how well the model is fitting on 'new' data that hasn't been used for fitting it.
The more flexible model (large polynomial order, or similarly small $\lambda$) is good at fitting and reducing the cost function. But on a new dataset it performs worse.




+1 I was about to post the same kind of idea, that the optimal in-sample ridge penalty is no penalty at all.

It is rare that one wants to do a regression such that the Euclidean norm of the coefficients $\beta_i$ are below to a specifically chosen $c$. In fact, $c$ is usually considered to be a hyperparameter chosen in hope that the regression yields coefficients with better generalizability without sacrificing too much accuracy. For each different values of $c$, you get different $(\lambda,\beta_i)$ solutions to the optimization problem in your question, but at the same time we discover that smaller values of $c$ lead to larger values of $\lambda$. Now that we understand the association between $\lambda$ and $c$, we can forgo $c$ completely and just treat $\lambda$ as a hyperparameter, knowing that increasing $\lambda$ will shrink the coefficients.
